# Android Studio Flamingo Missing SDK Windows 10

Tags: android-studio, sdk, radiance-flamingo

Does anyone have any idea HOW to fix this Missing SDK error?
Many hours have been spent trying,
unchecking hide obsolete,
changing sys env var's with JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_HOME paths,
deleting the auto created .android folder
editing sdk path in Android studio- (sdkmanager) and
downloading cmdline-tools for a manual cmd install.
Then when trying to install through cmd prompt, I get the "failed to download any source lists" error. Really at a loss here. Feels like I tried everything. Any help is infinitely welcome and appreciated!!!!

Tried manually installing and all of the above expecting error to go away.
Instead it threw another error and the first missing SDK error still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I've just selected Java's JDK (I had it before) in the top right corner, not Embedded or any other options - Java's JDK.

It works.

Comment: So there is no issue that I know of with Java (JDK)...The problem I have is missing SDK. Has anyone else had this and fixed it? I've downloaded SDK Manager separately and tried manually installing through command prompt. All to no avail.

Comment: @ClementineRind try fresh install then. If not working - install previous version.

Comment: Ah already tried both but thanks!